# Javascript join multiple arrays with & but I get duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, duplicates

I have this project in which I create a link with multiple arrays that are joined with & signs. It works perfectly, but when I get more than 3 arrays, it doesn't. When I skip a couple of questions I get a & sign at the beginning of the string and when I only choose the first it adds one to the end which is bad. Also if I choose the first and the last array and skip the rest there a multiple & added between while I always just want 1.

I use this to join the arrays:

```
/**
         * Returns the parameters for the URL.
         *
         * @returns {string}
         */
        getLink() {
            this.tmp = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < this.url.length; i++) {
                // Check if question is from the same quiz part and adds a , between chosen answers and add the right prefix at the beginning
                if (this.url[i].length > 0) {
                    this.tmp.push("" + Quiz[i].prefix + this.url[i].join(","))
                }
                // if the link is empty remove everything that was added (& an ,)
                if (this.url[i].length === 0) {
                    this.tmp.push("");
                }
            }
            /// If answers are from different quiz parts add a & between answers
            return "" + this.tmp.join("&");
        }
```

Quiz and this.url are the arrays and .prefix and stuff are keys of the arrays.

This is what I use to check the link string to remove the unwanted & signs:

```
        LinkChecker(link) {
            let cleanLink = link.split('&&').join('&');
            if (cleanLink[0] === '&') {
                cleanLink = cleanLink.slice(1);
            }
            if (cleanLink[cleanLink.length - 1] === '&') {
                cleanLink = cleanLink.slice(0, -1);
            }
            return cleanLink;
            console.log(cleanLink.length)
        }
```

And this is something I tried now:

```
            let i = 0;
            let LastLink = '';
            let FirstLink = LastLink;
            let link = this.LinkChecker(this.getLink());
            if (link[link.length -1] === '&'){
                LastLink = link.slice(0, -1);
            }
            while(i == '&'){
                if(LastLink[i] === '&'){
                    FirstLink = link.slice(-1, 0);
                }
                i++
            }
            console.log(FirstLink)
```

But it also doesn't really work.

Preview:

> bd_shoe_size_ids=6621&&&

> &&manufacturer_ids=5866

> bd_shoe_size_ids=6598&&&manufacturer_ids=5866

It's supposed to look like:

> bd_shoe_size_ids=6598&manufacturer_ids=5866

Comment: in your linkChecker you probably want to split using `&`, filter out any empty entries and then rejoin using `&` again

Comment: Please add a sample of url string so we can run code with an example.

Comment: Remove the whole block that does `push("")`. This causes the array to still have an entry for something you want to discard -- don't push in that case.

Comment: Unrelated, but the use of `Quiz[i]` and `this.url[i]` shows you are not applying OOP principles correctly. Also, `Quiz` seems to be a global variable -- that's bad practice.

Comment: @trincot I know it's not the best but I'm still learning oop and I'm doing it on my own this project is meant to be something to learn of because I never used oop before so it's not supposed to be perfect. That will come later on. But  your solution did work thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to avoid than to fix (the double `&`).

Remove the whole block that does `push("")`. This push is adding an entry to your array that you really don't want to have at all, so just don't push it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `LinkChecker` method only considers pairs of `&`s. You can handle any number of `&`s by splitting and filtering out any empty entries in the array:

```
      LinkChecker(link) {
            // split by & and then filter out the blank entries
            let cleanLink = link
                .split('&')
                .filter((section) => section !== '') // remove any empty strings
                .join('&');
            if (cleanLink[0] === '&') {
                cleanLink = cleanLink.slice(1);
            }
            if (cleanLink[cleanLink.length - 1] === '&') {
                cleanLink = cleanLink.slice(0, -1);
            }
            return cleanLink;
            console.log(cleanLink.length)
        }
```

As others have mentioned, there are ways to solve this in your array creation but since your LinkChecker seems to be where you are cleaning them specifically, I only changed that method for the sake of clarity.